# How to understand question about text document similarity

Tags: python

My teacher rarely answers emails so forgive me for asking here. I'm having trouble understanding what he means about the highlighted part:

"Create a python program that will compute the text document similarity between different documents. Your implementation will take a **list of documents as an input text corpus** and it will compute a dictionary of words for the given corpus."

So is the input a list of strings like so: `e = ["a", "a", "b", "f"]`

Or is it just a list with a single string where I pull the individual words?

Full question:

Create a python program that will compute the text document similarity between different documents. Your implementation will take a list of documents as an input text corpus and it will compute a dictionary of words for the given corpus. Later, when a new document (i.e search document) is provided, your implementation should provide a list of documents that are similar to the given search document, in descending order of their similarity with the search document. For computing similarity between any two documents in our question, you can use the following distance measures (optionally you can also use any other measure as well).

1.dot product between the two vectors

2.distance norm (or Euclidean distance) between two vectors .e.g.||u−v||

Hint A text document can be represented as a word vector against a given dictionary of words. So first compute the dictionary of words for a given text corpus, containing the unique words from the documents of given corpus. Then transform every text document of the given corpus into vector form i.e. creating a word vector where 0 indicates the word is not in the document and 1 indicates that the word is present in the given document. In our question, a text document is just represented as a string, so the text corpus is nothing but a list of strings

Comment: How can it be a single string, if you need to compare different documents?

Comment: hold on i'll post the full question

Comment: From the NLP classes I had i think the input would be something like `corpus = ['my very long document 1', 'a second document', 'a third', '...']` a corpus would be a collection of documents, and a document would be a sequence of words (from a single word to a whole bookn, or a sentence, a twitt, an utterance, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand it you are given a list of documents and you will match a new document to them, for instance:

```
my_docs = ["this is the first doc", "this is the second doc", "and this is yet another doc"]
inpd = input('please enter a document: ')
my_vocab, v_dim = build_vocab(my_docs + [inpd]) # build vocabulary from doclist and new doc
my_vdocs = [build_dvec(doc, v_dim, my_vocab) for doc in my_docs] # vectorize documents
inpdv = build_dvec(inpd, v_dim, my_vocab) # vectorize input document

print('docs and score: ', [str(my_docs[itm[0]])+': '+str(itm[1]) for itm in dmtch(inpdv, my_vdocs)])
```

this would produce

```
please enter a document: yet another doc
docs and score:  ['and this is yet another doc: 3.0', 'this is the first doc: 1.0', 'this is the second doc: 1.0']
```

The best match is the last document in your list as it contains the most words from the input document.  I have omitted the code for constructing the vocabulary, transforming the documents to vectors and matching them (=assignment).